# Efficient algorithm to reduce peak power from multiple pwm output?

Tags: algorithm, controls, pwm

I have multiple power mosfet pwm controlled and connected to a single main power supply.
Thee pwm signals operate all at the same frequency and their duty factor is determined otherwise and can change frequently. It can can vary between 0 and 100%.
My PWM controller  allows me to choose On time and off time independently for each signal.

I am looking for an efficient algorithm to determine the on time of each channel in order to minimize the peak power drawn from the power supply.

A trivial example: With 10 mosfet each one with a 10% duty factor the optimal solution will be to turn on each mosfet one at a time in sequence.

Any ideas out there on how to address this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Please add an non trivial example and what you expect as output.

Comment: The trivial example seems to assume *On-state power output* to be equal among outputs (as well as power balance in *Off-state*). I like such to be explicit. (Unrelated: Elaborate forms of this go *noise shaping*.)

Comment: reading the comments above I realize my question was poorly written and I apologize for that, So yes all mosfet draw the same power when Open. and my question is really, given the duty factor of all the mosfet ( so we know how much energy has to be delivered by the PS during one period)  how to optimize the sequencing of the opening of the mosfet to minimize fluctuation of the instant total power drawn from the power supply during this one period.

Comment: (`all [MOSFETs] draw the same power when Open` I think I see why you didn't post to [Electrical engineering@SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pwm). It doesn't hurt to mention your background or use the help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No need to apologise where you invested the effort you found justified.)

Comment: Hope this is just for single direction of current (half bridge / unipolar control) otherwise you would need to pair current source and sinks together (switching them in the "same" times). How about dead times? do you have any or no short circuit is possible in your current setup.

Comment: @Spektre 21 Thanks for the comment but this is not an issue: all mosftet are high side and drive electrically independent loads.

Comment: `all [MOSFETs] are high side and drive electrically independent loads` please put such information in the question body. Upfront would have been helpful (then again, hopes are wisdom grows).

Comment: @greybard Yes I realize it now. I was seeing the problem as an algorithmic question (this is why I posted it here and not on electrical where I am also active). I did not fully  appreciate that these info could have been helpful. even the way to ask the question was not easy for me. The wanted result is to "smooth" as much as possible " the output of the main PS by being smart about selecting Mosfet OnTime. Optimal solution I devised was through a  least square optimisation routine. I coded it but it was way to slow to be run in real time. The proposed solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the pulse width fractions (between 0 and 1) be p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>n</sub>. Let s<sub>0</sub> = 0 and s<sub>n</sub> = s<sub>n−1</sub> + p<sub>n</sub> be the prefix sums. Signal i should turn on at times s<sub>i−1</sub> mod 1 and end at times s<sub>i</sub> mod 1.

This algorithm does what you want on the trivial example, since s<sub>0</sub>, s<sub>1</sub>, ..., s<sub>n−1</sub>, s<sub>n</sub> = 0, 1/10, ..., 9/10, 0.

For a less trivial example, suppose that we have signals at 10%, 20%, 30%, 40%, 50%, 60%, 70%, 80%, 90%. Then the pulses look like

```
1---------1---------
-22--------22-------
---333-------333----
------4444------4444
55555-----55555-----
6----666666----66666
-7777777---7777777--
888888--88888888--88
99999-999999999-9999
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple solution however I would probably improve it a bit by first computing the GCD of all possible/used ratios and then generate the pattern for GCD PWM periods to avoid more glitches ... maybe even use symmetrical phase PWM for next GCD PWM periods

Comment: Thanks its simple, fast and elegant